# Django querystring/slug inside of formclass

Tags: django

Is it possibe to get the id slug inside of the get_form_class?  Any advice?

```
class Create(Merchant_Services_Editor_Mixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'secure/shared/editor.html'

    def get_form_class(self):

        if (self.request.GET.get("id") == 1):
            return _Merchant_Services_Form.StripeEditor
        else:
            return _Merchant_Services_Form.BraintreeEditor
```

Comment: what do you mean by the "id slug"? You want "the slug" or "the id" or "the id of the object with that slug" or "the slug of the object with that id"? What is your querystring parameters, is it slug or id?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your id slug to your form using `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class MyView(CreateView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(MyView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        kwargs['id'] = self.request.GET.get('id')
        return kwargs
```

Then you'll have to update your form class to handle this new parameter. You can retrieve it from kwargs:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.pop('id', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```